# Azure service bus - Read messages sent by .NET Core 2 with BrokeredMessage.GetBody

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am using .NET Core 2 for an application which needs to put a message on the Service bus and read by a legacy .NET 4.6 receiver. The receiver listens to messages from other legacy applications as well.

**Legacy sender:**

```
UserData obj = new UserData()
{
  id = 1,
  name = "Alisha"
};
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(consentInstated);
_client.Send(message);
```

**Legacy Receiver:**

```
var dataObj = objBrokeredMessage.GetBody<UserData>();
businessFunc(dataObj.id, dataObj.name);
```

**.NET Core 2 sender:** as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069423/1773900

```
var ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(UserData));
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ser.WriteObject(ms, objUserData);
var message = new Message(ms.ToArray());
_client.Send(message);
```

However, the reciever fails to deserialize the message and throws the following error

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an
>   error deserializing the object of type UserData. The input source is
>   not correctly formatted. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The input
>   source is not correctly formatted.

What can I do to make both senders work with the same receiver?

Comment: Looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069423/122195

Comment: I have used the same strategy as described in the link. GetBody() still throws parsing error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BrokeredMessage` is using XML Binary Reader to deserialize the messages. So your sending part should look like this:

```cs
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(UserData));
var ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlDictionaryWriter binaryDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms);
ser.WriteObject(binaryDictionaryWriter, obj);
binaryDictionaryWriter.Flush();
var message = new Message(ms.ToArray());
```

Comment: The receiver can now parse the object but it loses values, and the properties are all set to null

Comment: There seems to be a problem in the way the data is serialized. The byte array formed is different from what the BrokeredMessage creates.

Comment: @lohiarahul I just tested and sending from new client to old client works with my code. Could you identify which difference your messages have (receive `Stream`, convert to `string` and compare)? E.g. could it be the message classes are in different namespaces?

Comment: Is your receiver the same as mentioned in the question? I created a byte array using the BrokeredMessage and one with the solution you provided. The arrays created are not the same. Even the length differs.

Comment: Yes, same. Please convert both arrays to string to see the difference.

Comment: It works. Turns out that the `UserData` had two slightly different implementations with the same name in different namespaces at the receiver and the sender. Bummer.

Comment: This answer is a life saver! Thanks @MikhailShilkov

Answer (score 3):

We could send serialize json Object string directly from .net core side, and we could get the message with following code in the .net side.  It works correctly on my side.

```
var dataObj = message.GetBody<UserData>(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserData)));
```

**.net core** side send message code:

```
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objUserData));
_client.SendAsync(new Message{Body = body,ContentType = "text/plain"}).Wait();
```

**.net side** receive message code:

```
var dataObj = message.GetBody<UserData>(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserData)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem, but neither solution worked. For me below code works

```cs
// model is the object that you want to sent to Topic
Model model = new Model();
var serializator = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlDictionaryWriter binaryDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(memoryStream);
serializator.WriteObject(binaryDictionaryWriter, json);
binaryDictionaryWriter.Flush();
// below message can be sent to Topic via .NET Core  and will be properly deserialized in .NET Framework subscriber
var message = new Message(memoryStream.ToArray());
var client = new TopicClient(_endpoint, _channelName );
await client.SendAsync(message);
```