# Azure ServiceBus message from .net core does not parse in .net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure, queue, azureservicebus

I have a ServiceBus in Azure and a number of queues.
I have one service written in **.net core** which sends data into the queue like so:

```
queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);
string example = "Hello World!";
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example));
await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
```

Other service, written in **.net framework** 4.6.1 is listening on that same queue like so:

```
queueClient.OnMessage(ProcessQMessage);
private void ProcessQMessage (BrokeredMessage receivedMessage) {
    var tmpBytes = receivedMessage.GetBody<byte[]>();
    ...
}
```

For some reason i get an exception from receivedMessage.GetBody(). I get the same exception trying to parse it to **string** and **object** as well:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Byte[]. The input source is not correctly formatted.

I understand that the problem comes from the fact that core and framework work a little differently. Didn't expect this to be a problem though.

Comment: Any process now? If you still have any problem, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I decided to move away from .net core, so it is no longer relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If the systems are running with old client, you will be likely stuck with `XmlObjectSerializer` (data contract serializer) like our .netfull client. But things will not be broken. Sample code is like below which is exactly what happens underneath in the .netfull client.

```
var bytes = your bytes;
var serializer = DataContractBinarySerializer<byte[]>.Instance;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, bytes);
    var msg = new Message(stream.ToArray());
    var client = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient(ConnectionString, Queue);
    await client.SendAsync(msg);
    await client.CloseAsync();
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/239#issuecomment-320820562) and this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427361/azure-service-bus-read-messages-sent-by-net-core-2-with-brokeredmessage-getbo?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: You demonstrate how to send data into the queue, this part works fine. I can also recive these messages justfine as long as I send and receive it from the same framework. My question is how to send it from .net Core and receive it correctly in .net Framework 4.6.1